# How to name a machine learning algorithm where we used very small amount of labeled data?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, neural-networks, algorithms

I have to describe a machine-learning algorithm that needs only very small dataset. I cannot say it is unsupervised because I already used the labels in the training. Also, I cannot say semi-supervised because I did not mixed ublabeled data with small labeled data. I cannot say also weakly-supervised because the labels are precise.
I know that it is supervised but I would like to have an adjective that describe better that I used only small amount of labeled data. 
I would like to attract attention that my algorithm only need small amount of labeled data
What is the best adjective to use?

Comment: data-efficient?

Comment: Good suggestion. Is it used in the machine learning comunity?

Comment: enough that i've heard of it :)

Comment: In every machine learning algorithms, we used data. Here I mean that the algorithm needs a small amount of supervision. Can I say label-efficient?